# How the meta tags of a method work?

Tags: c#

I've got this meta `SoapHeader`, `SoapDocumentMethod`...how can I know when they are executed?, before the method is executed or after it is executed? and where is the method that this metas are executing? what name it has?

```
[SoapHeader("AgentInfoHeaderValue")]
[SoapDocumentMethod("http://www.example.com/xml/andromeda#WORK", RequestNamespace = "http://www.example.com/xml/someapi", ResponseNamespace = "http://www.example.com/xml/someapi", 
    Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
[return: XmlElement("return", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false, DataType = "base64Binary")]
public byte[] WORK([XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.example.com/xml/someapi", DataType = "string", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)] string guid, [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.example.com/xml/someapi", DataType = "base64Binary", Form = XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)] byte[] data)
{
   //some actions
}
```

Comment: They aren't executed, they just decorate the method with metadata. They are called attributes.

Comment: @DavidArno what do you mean by "decorate"?

Comment: Please have a read of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx. This will begin to explain attributes to you.